# BarChart is not showing correct dynamic data

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have implemented bar chart where data will come dynamically. In my code data is coming from server but the graph is not show correct data it shows only -1, 0 and 1 position. I am using `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4` library for bar chart.

Below is my fragment class

```
public class MonthsFragment extends Fragment {

public String user_id;
// Session Manager Class
UserSessionManager session;

BarChart chartUniqueVisitors;
ArrayList<BarEntry> BARENTRY ;
ArrayList<String> BarEntryLabels ;
BarDataSet Bardataset ;
BarData BARDATA ;

public float jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec;

public MonthsFragment(){}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unique_visitors, container, false);

    session = new UserSessionManager(getContext());
    session.checkLogin();
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    user_id = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_USER_ID);
    return view;
}

    private void getDataForBusinessAddress() {
        String URL ="XYZ.php?username="+user_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("Response montghly____",response);

                JSONArray jsonarray = null;
                try {
                    jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        jan = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Jan"));
                        feb = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Feb"));
                        mar = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Mar"));
                        apr = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Apr"));
                        may = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("May"));
                        jun = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Jun"));
                        jul = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Jul"));
                        aug = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Aug"));
                        sep = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Sep"));
                        oct = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Oct"));
                        nov = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Nov"));
                        dec = Float.parseFloat(jsonobject.getString("Dece"));
                        AddValuesToBARENTRY(jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.getCache().clear();
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    chartUniqueVisitors = (BarChart) v.findViewById(R.id.chartUniqueVisitors);

    getDataForBusinessAddress();

    BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
    AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();
    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");
    BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);
    Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
}
```

AddValuesToBARENTRY function to add response data to BARENTRY ArrayList

```
 public void AddValuesToBARENTRY(float jan, float feb, float mar, float apr, float may, float jun, float jul, float aug, float sep, float oct, float nov, float dec){
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(jan, 0));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(feb, 1));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(mar, 2));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(apr, 3));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(may, 4 ));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(jun, 5 ));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(jul, 6));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(aug, 7));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(sep, 8));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(oct, 9));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(nov, 10));
    BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(dec, 11));
    chartUniqueVisitors.setData(BARDATA);
}
```

AddValuesToBarEntryLabels function to add the values on Barchat

```
public void AddValuesToBarEntryLabels(){
    BarEntryLabels.add("Jan");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Feb");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Mar");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Apr");
    BarEntryLabels.add("May");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Jun");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Jul");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Aug");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Sep");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Oct");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Nov");
    BarEntryLabels.add("Dec");
  }
 }
```

Output is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V1Hc.png), which is not correct format thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in filling BarEntry

```
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(jan, 0));
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(feb, 1));
```

It should be :

```
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(0, jan));
BARENTRY.add(new BarEntry(1, feb));
```

First value index (x Value) second is actual value - height of BAR (that comes fom server).

Also call `setData` once on onCreate method, now you call it in loop, and it is called multiple time.

```
chartUniqueVisitors.setData(BARDATA);
```

Here what I got with your data

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply sir, but now the chart is show nothing

Comment: I've updated my answer, See screenshot how I changed your code: 
I've copied your code, filled data like I pointed on screen, and moved setData to the end, and it showed result.

Comment: I think you are adding static data that's why it shown on chart. In my case I am using dynamic data. And I used same what ever you said

Comment: Yes it is static, since I can't debug your server data :) I gave you solution based on what you posted. If problem is with data, you should debug it

Comment: I used debug and the response data is coming

Comment: Myabe catch block is being called, while parsing Json ?

catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: Catch block is not called because the data is also coming on AddValuesToBARENTRY function. I used log there and data is coming like this jan___: 604.0

Comment: I think, I can't help you based on information you provided. And I think answer is hidden in response JSON, that is not visible in question text. If you can post it somewhere like https://pastebin.com/, I will take a look at it and help you

Comment: I've checked and it works.
http://prntscr.com/k9wpv4

The only modification I've done was removing first parameter of BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);
and I have = new BarData(Bardataset);

It is because I use v3.0.3' of MPAndroidChart, and it accepts only 1 parameter constructor

Comment: I don't know how you did this because I am following all of your instruction but it's not working

Comment: And now the app is also crash and give this error  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0`

Comment: It's working now sir, I just add `BARENTRY = new ArrayList<>();
    BarEntryLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
    AddValuesToBarEntryLabels();
    Bardataset = new BarDataSet(BARENTRY, "Projects");
    BARDATA = new BarData(BarEntryLabels, Bardataset);
    Bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);` below the for loop

Comment: Great ! I am happy the problem is solved :) Have a nice day